# "make[2]: g++: Command not found" in Netbeans

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, g++

I get the error message:

> make[2]: g++: Command not found

which I know means it cannot find the C++ compiler. However, in Netbeans if I go to the configuration to choose my C++ compiler it shows the following being in `/usr/bin`:

```
g++4.6
g++4.7
g++4.8
```

but it doesn't have just `g++`.

Tried `sudo aptitude install g++` but it didnt work.

If I do `g++ --version` I get:

```
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder
```

Comment: Try `sudo aptitude install g++`

Comment: Could I Just ask, whats the difference between g++ and g++ v.vv?

Comment: Nah that suggestion you made didnt work.......

Answer (score 1):

1) Verify you can run "g++" from the command line,

2) type `whereis g++` to get the path,

3) Make sure you have the [NetBeans C++ plugin](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/cpp-setup-instructions.html) installed

> Go to Tools->Options->C++->Build Tools

4) [Configure the path](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/cpp-setup-instructions.html) in NetBeans

Comment: I definitely have g++ but I had 4.7 installed and I upgraded to 4.8 g++ (and 4.8 GCC). When I next opened Netbeans it detected these changes. GCC was still set to "GCC" in Netbeansconfig and g++ was set to "g++" but there is no "g++" file in /usr/bin/

Comment: Have edited question to show what happens with g++ --version.

Comment: Failing all else, create a symbolic link: `cd /usr/bin;ln -s g++4.8 g++`

Comment: Permission denied (I added sudo at the beginning) :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `/usr/bin/g++` is a *symlink* to some `/usr/bin/g++-4.7` (or `g++-4.8` etc...); just make it again (which is usually provided by the `g++` *virtual* package on Debian or Ubuntu), e.g.

```
   % sudo -s
   # cd /usr/bin
   # ln -sv g++-4.8 g++
```

<sup>Above `%` and `#` are shell prompts that you should not type.</sup>

Of course, don't forget the `sudo apt-get install g++` etc...

BTW, you might put that link from `$HOME/bin/g++` to `/usr/bin/g++-4.8` and you don't need root permission for that.

(sometimes, these symlinks go *indirectly* thru `/etc/alternatives` etc...)

Your issue is a sysadmin issue; you should rather ask it (with a big lot more details) on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/); it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

BTW, NetBeans is not a compiler, but an editor (sometimes called IDE). You could use something better/simpler (e.g. `emacs` or `vim`) with e.g. `make` as a builder (to be run inside a terminal). Before using NetBeans ensure that `g++ -v` is working alone in some terminal